# How to modify BigCommerce store HTML with app

Tags: plugins, bigcommerce, stenciljs

I am new to BigCommerce app dev. For now I want to create an app that modify Product order Page but for now I'm stuck I haven't found any documentation about how to inject new HTML to the store.

I didn't post any code or script because I didn't even start.

Comment: Questions that ask "where do I start?" are typically too broad and are not a good fit for this site. People have their own method for approaching the problem and because of this there cannot be a _correct_ answer. Give a good read over [Where to Start](//softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6367) and [edit] your post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 approaches you could take, depending on how you need to modify the template:

The Scripts API allows you to inject JavaScript into the theme, which would allow you to manipulate the DOM using JS:
https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api-docs/storefront/scripts-overview

The Widgets API allows you to inject HTML, CSS, and JS into pre-defined "regions" in Stencil themes:
https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api-docs/storefront/widgets/widgets-overview